# Printing out a multiplication table

Tags: java, variables, while-loop

I'm going through the Java Tutorial on HackerRank using Java 8. The goal is to print out a multiplication table of 2 from 1 - 10.

Here is what I came up with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 2;
    int y = 0;
    int z;

    while (y < 10) {

        z = x * y;
        y++;

        System.out.println(x + " x " + y + " = " + z); 
    }
```

Here is the output I get from the code above

- 2 x 1 = 0
- 2 x 2 = 2
- 2 x 3 = 4
- 2 x 4 = 6
- 2 x 5 = 8
- 2 x 6 = 10
- 2 x 7 = 12
- 2 x 8 = 14
- 2 x 9 = 16
- 2 x 10 = 18

I've also tried while <= 10 instead of while < 10 as shown in my code above and for that my result was:

- 2 x 1 = 0
- 2 x 2 = 2
- 2 x 3 = 4
- 2 x 4 = 6
- 2 x 5 = 8
- 2 x 6 = 10
- 2 x 7 = 12
- 2 x 8 = 14
- 2 x 9 = 16
- 2 x 10 = 18
- 2 x 11 = 20

Neither of this outputs is what I'm looking for. Logically I am confident my code makes sense and should work so I'm looking for someone to give me tips as to something I may have missed or maybe I've made a mistake and I'm not aware of it. I am not looking for the code to the right answer, but rather advice and/or pointers which will allow to come up with a working solution on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start your y value at 1
2. Don't increment your y value until after the print statement

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {    
     int x = 2;

     int y = 1; //starts at 1
     int z;

     while (y < 10) {

       z = x * y;

       System.out.println(x + " x " + y + " = " + z); 
       y++; // increment y after the print statement
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you. i feel silly for missing such a small detail.

Answer (score 0):

Assign value of y = 1 and  increment it after your system.out.println();